# How to center the headerRight icon button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use the react-navigation to set the header and headerRight.
but my headerRight icon button cannot be centered on the right.

[image]

following is my code

```
  Activate_qrscan: {
    screen: Activate_qrscan,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: '123',
      headerRight: (
      <Button
        transparent
        onPress={ () => navigation.dispatch(navigateAction) }>
        <Icon
          name='close'
          style={ { color: 'white' } } />
      </Button>

      ),
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#3b5998',
      },
      headerRightContainerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      },

      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'normal',
      },
    }),
  },
```

I have added the headerRightContainerStyle but it still not work!
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just add this to make it center - `alignSelf: 'center'`

Comment: sorry,not work for me :(

Comment: Then you can manually add some margin to top and bottom to make it in center.

Comment: Note that manually add some margin will not work on every screen size

Comment: That is why I do not want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the button from `react-native-elements`, it adds bloat, and some stylish that you may not even need, remove your `headerRightContainerStyle` and switch button for this code, be aware that you need the Icon class from `react-native-elements`.

```
  headerRight: (
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row",justifyContent: "flex-end",paddingRight:10,width: 120}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => console.log('Hey im centered')}
            >
            <Icon type="font-awesome" name="cog" color="white" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
```

Comment: Yes your right.
Do not put the third-party component into.

Comment: I was searching to implement style to header right button, Since styles are not working directly. But wrapping them in a view worked perfectly. Thanks!!